# Looking for a square feet pricing solution for flooring products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

On my Magneto 2 store I am looking to create a square-feet pricing solution for my flooring products. How can I implement a flooring sq-ft calculator that automatically calculates the price of flooring as the customer enters the desired dimension?

Note:I have multiple types of flooring products having different sizes & price.